# Inject script into website to change attribute of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's assume there is a website where the `background-color` attribute of `body` is set to white, would it be possible to write a script to change the background color of that page to another color e.g. black, and inject this script so it is always executed?

Or do i always have to open the developer console and change the `background-color` attribute of `body` manually by executing `document.body.backgroundColor="black"`?

Comment: Look for things like [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo).

Comment: There are also a couple of browser plugins called [stylebot](http://stylebot.me/about) and [stylish](https://userstyles.org/) that can re-style web sites (others too I'm sure).

Comment: If you are using chrome, maybe you can write a chrome extension, the content script part can make change to the web page easily.

Comment: Can you recommend any tutorials on how to write a chrome extension?

Comment: "bookmarklets" are the classical no-software manner of accomplishing such dynamic code injections.

Comment: @EdwardBlack, this can be a good tutorial for knowing the structure of a chrome extension development. I think as you are already familiar with Javascript. What you mainly need to know is the manifest.json file (it is a configuration file in chrome extension) and also the communication between background and content script if needed: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: A whole new extension seems like overkill for such a customization. A Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey/stylish/stylebot script seems more appropriate, in my opinion.